# Sharepoint designer workflow 2013: send 7 different email notifications based on a field in item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, if-condition

Based on a list with approval.

Conditions for workflow to fire the email is that item must be Approved and according to a choice value in the item (a, b, c, d ...) there is a different email to send.

I find myself creating the same If condition 7 times (If current item is approved AND Value is A).

Is there a way to write a better workflow? Like using the button 'parallel'.

Also all my 7 conditions are all one below the other, should I see after the fist one 'Else...'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will send different emails, I think you should use 7 if condition by using OOB workflow actions as below:

[image]

If you don’t want to use Else, you can all if condition to "Parallel Block" as below:

[image]

Comment: What would you use between the 2 examples you have provided?